Premiere pro: Reverse Match Frame not finding the frame in any other/duplicate clip
Short Wording:
If I’ve 2 identical clips in my Project Panel/same bin created from the same master clip, named Clip-1 and Clip-1b. Is there any way if I want to find any one particular frame of Clip-1 in Clip-1b?
Long wording:
I inserted clip-1 on Sequence-1, commanded Sequence> Match Frame, and the frame under Cti was loaded in the Src Pnl.
Now I deleted clip-1 from Seq1 and inserted clip-1b onto the same seq-1. And now I highlighted Src Pnl (it still has the frame showing from my earlier command). And commanded Sequence> Reverse Match Frame. Now should it/will it locate the frame my current clip-1b showing in the TL? (i've tried to show the same in the attached sshot).
If not, is there any other way to find and match a frame in 2 diff clips in the same project?

Its just not possible.
In Adobe Premier Pro, even exact duplicate clip of any existing clip (even if both are under same project, same or different sequences) is treated as a separate and different clip by Premiere Pro. You can't match any one frame of one clip into another, even if you do know that the said frame exists in both clips.
One work around is to setup multicam and synchornize timecodes on both/each clip. Then you can find frame of one clip into the other.
